# Python: Create list of objects OR Turn string into object

Tags: python

I have a python code in which I have a function that I want to go through a list of object instances and make changes to those instances if a certain condition is met. In other words, something like this:

```
def distToPlayers(self, list):
    self.playerlist = list
    returnls = []
    
    for i in self.playerlist:
        if distance(self.playerlist[i].xpos , self.playerlist[i].ypos) <= self.playerlist[i].catchRadius:
            returnls.append(self.playerlist[i])

        self.playerlist[i].caughtBall = True
   
    return returnls
```

Where distance() is just a function that gives a value, and list is a list of object instances, like receiver1. So, receiver1 has stats like xpos and ypos, and this function looks at all of the players in the list that is inputed, computes their distance to the self object, and returns a list of the players for whom the object running the function is within their catching radius.

My question is: how do I do this? My code gives me weird errors, like "List indices must be ints, not objects". My list indices shouldn't be objects, what is AT those indices should be objects, but whatever, maybe this just isn't something you're supposed to do. If anyone knows how to do this though, please let me know!

I also had the idea to instead input a list of strings that are the names of the objects I want to talk about ( so I would input:

`ball.distToPlayers(['receiver1', 'defback1', etc...])`   instead of `ball.distToPlayers([receiver1, defback1]) ) .` Then, I would convert those strings into object names inside the function. I know you can take convert strings to ints and floats and vice versa by saying, `int(x) or str(x)`. Is there a way to go from string to object instance? I've tried obj(x) and object(x), and neither seem to work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what went wrong. the `for .. in` syntax in python iterates over the objects in the list, not the indices. So `i` is the actual objects. You could use `enumerate` or `range` if you need the indices too.

Comment: @ Lone Lunatic    Yep. I posted this question without spending enough time looking at the error. Rookie mistake! You are totally right.

Comment: can be just `returnls = [x for x in list if distance(x.xpos , x.ypos) <= x.catchRadius]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def distToPlayers(self, lst):
    self.playerlist = lst
    returnls = []

    for player in self.playerlist:
        if distance(player.xpos , player.ypos) <= player.catchRadius:
            returnls.append(player)
            player.caughtBall = True

    return returnls
```

is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a silly goose!

You totally can create a list of objects. I just used bad syntax. In my loop, I said, "for i in list". This means that the things being iterated through ARE the list items, not the indices. The function works now that I replaced the self.playerlist[i]'s with just i .

Answer (score -1):

`for i in self.playerlist:` is the issue. `i` here represent ele in the list. The iteration in python doesn't represent index rather than the element itself.

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem:

- `for i in range(len(self.playerlist)))`
- `for i, elm in enumerate(self.playerlist)`
- `for player in self.playerlist` and then mutate player

```py
def distToPlayers(self, list):
    self.playerlist = list
    returnls = []
    
    for i in range(len(self.playerlist))):
        if distance(self.playerlist[i].xpos , self.playerlist[i].ypos) <= self.playerlist[i].catchRadius:
            returnls.append(self.playerlist[i])

        self.playerlist[i].caughtBall = True
   
    return returnls
```

Comment: Actually, `for player in ...` is much better than both `range` and `enumerate` since you never need the index